# Creating Column from a Mapping Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following mapping Dataframe where elements from the "model" column are assigned a type, a subtype and a group.

```
model <- c('ndev_atype', 'ndev_btype', 'ndev_ctype', 'pdev_atype', 'pdev_btype', 'pdev_ctype')
type <- c('n', 'n', 'n', 'p', 'p', 'p')
subtype <- c('type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type1', 'type2', 'type3')
group <- c('g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g1', 'g1', 'g2')
mapDF = data.frame(model, type, subtype, group)
```

This gives the following:

```
       model type subtype group
1 ndev_atype    n   type1    g1
2 ndev_btype    n   type2    g1
3 ndev_ctype    n   type3    g2
4 pdev_atype    p   type1    g1
5 pdev_btype    p   type2    g1
6 pdev_ctype    p   type3    g2
```

The following dataframe captures my experiment:

```
sample=sample(1:100, 10)
measure=c('ndev_ctype', 'pdev_atype', 'pdev_ctype', 'ndev_atype', 'pdev_ctype', 'ndev_btype', 'ndev_ctype', 'ndev_atype', 'pdev_btype', 'pdev_ctype')
measureDF <- data.frame(sample, measure)
```

this gives

```
measureDF
   sample    measure
1      94 ndev_ctype
2      34 pdev_atype
3      87 pdev_ctype
4      97 ndev_atype
5      33 pdev_ctype
6      19 ndev_btype
7      24 ndev_ctype
8      12 ndev_atype
9      77 pdev_btype
10     16 pdev_ctype
```

Question: Based on the "mapDF" mapping, what would you recommend to create columns 'measureDF$type', 'measureDF$subtype' and 'measureDF$group' columns ?

Comment: Are you just looking for `merge`? Something like `merge(mapDF, measureDF, by.y = "measure", by.x = "model")`? By the way, if you're going to use `sample` in your sample code, please also use `set.seed()`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yup, that's all I needed, thank you. No, I just used the sample to illustrate the issue. I have posted your answer as below. Please Edit as you please. Thx !

Comment: No problem. Do be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" to signal to others that the question has been resolved. Thanks!

Comment: I tried but it says: "You Cannot Accept your own answer". Why don't you pick cp/paste the answer and post it. I'll remove mine and accept yours :-) Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a problem for `merge`.

Since you don't have matching column names, you need to specify what columns to merge on.

"`by.x`" would be the column from the first `data.frame` and "`by.y`" would be the column from the second `data.frame`:

So, you can do this:

```
merge(mapDF, measureDF, by.y = "measure", by.x = "model")
```

and this gave the expected result

```
        model type subtype group sample
1  ndev_atype    n   type1    g1     97
2  ndev_atype    n   type1    g1     12
3  ndev_btype    n   type2    g1     19
4  ndev_ctype    n   type3    g2     94
5  ndev_ctype    n   type3    g2     24
6  pdev_atype    p   type1    g1     34
7  pdev_btype    p   type2    g1     77
8  pdev_ctype    p   type3    g2     87
9  pdev_ctype    p   type3    g2     33
10 pdev_ctype    p   type3    g2     16
```